# How to get primitive value from Future object (Future<int>) in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting Future instance while getting sharedPreference value as follows

```
 Future<int>  getCounterValue() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getInt("counter") ;
   }
```

Then I want to **get int value** from that Future instance. Please  help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get back from async execution to sync execution.

You can only get the value by using `await` or `.then((param) { print(param); })`

You would need to provide more context to make a concrete suggestion about how to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks I got by using  .then((param) { print(param); }) approach but  as we do in android java while getting value from shared preference it comes directly to value Is there any way to do same in flutter.

Comment: There is no such way. All communication from Flutter to the native platform is async so shared preferences has to be async as well.

Answer (score 3):

For **non-async** method:

```
void methodSync() {
  getCounterValue().then(
    (value){
      // do something with value
      print(value);
    }
  );
}
```

For **async** method:

```
void methodAsync() async{
  int value = await getCounterValue();
  // do something with value
  print(value);
}
```