# Convert Future<int> to int in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) and I am getting rows count of specific record via below code:

```
  Future<int> getNumberOfUsers() async {
    Database db = await database;
    final count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users'));
    return count;
  }
```

```
  Future<int> getCount() async {
    DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    int counter = await helper.getNumberOfUsers();
    return counter;
  }
```

I want to get the result of this function into int variable to use it inside `onPressed` in `FloatingActionButton`

```
int count = getCount();
int countParse = int.parse(getCount());
```

```
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          kBackgroundImage,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: kButtonBorderColor,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AddScreen(
                  (String newTitle) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        //--------------------------------------------
                        //I want to get the value here
                        int count = getCount();
                        int countParse = int.parse(getCount());
                        //--------------------------------------------
                        if (newTitle != null && newTitle.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                          _save(newTitle);
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

but I am getting this exception:

> A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.

Comment: It seems you already know how to use the `await` keyword. Can you explain why it would not be sufficient here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get primitive value from Future object (Future<int>) in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569223/how-to-get-primitive-value-from-future-object-futureint-in-flutter)

Comment: Either use a `FutureBuilder` or use `await` keyword in order to get `Future`'s value.

Comment: @nvoigt this line of code will cause exception int count = getCount(); I want to get the value as an integer and then check that it is not greater than 100

Comment: I know what you want. But you have used the method to resolve a `Future<T>` to a `T` 3 times in the code you posted. Why is that not good enough now? Why can't you use it a fourth time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this by adding async for OnPressed

```
onPressed: () async {...}
```

then use this line fo code

```
int count = await getCount();
```

thx

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to set the keyword "await" before calling the Future:

what you do:

```
int count = getCount();
```

what is correct:

```
int count = await getCount();
```

Answer (score 2):

use `await` to get response of `Future`

```
int number = await getNumberOfUsers();

int count = await getCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to add the "await" keyword before calling the function
```

int count = await getCount();