# Flutter SQFLite - how to count all records in a table

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am using Flutter with SQFLite.

I need to count all records in a table.

I have the following problematic code:

```
Future<int> countAllTasks() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final int result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM $myTable');
    return result;
  }
```

Issue: A value of type 'List<Map<String, Object?>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Could you please advise how to correctly count all records in a table. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try like this .Hope it will solve your problem

```
Future<int> countAllTask() async {
        final db = await instance.dataBase;
        var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $myTable');
        int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
        return count;
      }
```

Comment: This is how it only works: Future<int?> countAllTasks() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    var result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $myTable');
    int? count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
    return count;
  }, but when I say: int allRowsCount = DBHelper.instance.countAllTasks(); - I get error A value of type 'Future<int?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Comment: Try like this it will work .  int allRowsCount = await DBHelper.instance.countAllTasks() @DktPhl2018

Comment: Hello! I don't understand your answer. It is the same statement as I had before: int allRowsCount = DBHelper.instance.countAllTasks(); - this is not working.

Comment: I found answer myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929613/convert-futureint-to-int-in-flutter-dart - Thank You

Comment: There is another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097847/how-to-get-the-number-of-rows-in-a-database-table-with-flutter-sqflite

Comment: Main Page SQFlite Info: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md#sqlite-schema-information